# C++11 "correct" way for delayed execution

Tags: c++, c++11, scheduler

Is this a "clean" way to do delayed execution in C++11?  Or is there a "cleaner" way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  boost::thread t([] () { boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000)); std::cout << "rawr!" << std::endl; } );

  t.join();
}
```

Spawning a new thread and doing a sleep() seems excessively heavy?

Comment: There is `std::async`, but beware of the launch policy...

Comment: You should be able to call boost::this_thread::sleep in the main thread without creating a new thread

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, if the job is rather short, you should use an event-based system where you can just insert jobs with a certain time delay and they get executed after that. There's really no need for threads, you can do everything in the main thread.

Your main loop would look a little bit like this:

```
int main() {
    setup();

    while (true) {
        handleEvents();
        doYourOwnStuff();
        usleep(nextEvent.firingTime - currentTime); // Wait until the next event is triggered
    }
}
```

Of course, a system like this wouldn't be easy to implement if you already have a system. Many of the popular UI frameworks (Cocoa, Qt, Windows) support this design because it's extremely powerful and simple.

Comment: The problem w. such an approach is that I want the "action" to only be executed at (roughly) X amount of time. A while-loop approach would require me to sleep() and wake up "once-in-a-while" and check if times up to execute my "action". Or correct me if I'm wrong that I am missing something...

Comment: No, because you know when the next event is going to happen and you can sleep until that happens.

Comment: Why `usleep`? Shouldn't the event dispatcher block until the next event is ready?  That allows you to respond to e.g. new IO events immediately.

Comment: I used usleep because it's fairly accurate and my example will just wait until the next event is ready. Of course, a better one would be to use inter-thread messaging but that's too much code for this simple example.